# how to call this Jquery function on Button Click event?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net

I wanna call this jquery function in ASP.NET on button click event

```
var doRedirect = function() { location.href='http://www.example.com' };
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#label1").show();
    window.setTimeout("$('#label1').fadeOut('slow', doRedirect)", 10000);
});
```

Comment: in .net you can call it as a attribute right??

Answer (score 2):

If your jQuery is inline, you can do the following:

```
var doRedirect = function() { location.href='http://www.example.com' };
$("#<%=button1.ClientId%>").click(function() {
    $("#<%=label1.ClientId%>").show();
    window.setTimeout("$('#<%=label1.ClientId%>').fadeOut('slow', doRedirect)", 10000);
});
```

If it isn't inline (i.e. in a file), you will need to get the client control Id's you want to use in a different way, for example wrapping them in a `div` with an ID and selecting them through the `div`:

```
<div id="myId">
   <asp:Label runat="server" id="label1" />
   <asp:Button runat="server" id="button1" />
</div>

var doRedirect = function() { location.href='http://www.example.com' };
$("#myId input").click(function() {
    $("#myId span").show();
    window.setTimeout("$('#myId span').fadeOut('slow', doRedirect)", 10000);
});
```

Note that I am using the output HTML element types as the descendant in the jQuery selector.